Flutter Agora startRecording() with RecorderStreamType.preview return error code -3
I want to record the local video stream from Agora, including audio, and save it to the device's gallery. However, I don't want to use Agora's Cloud Recording feature. Thanks in advance!
I have used createMediaRecorder with type is RecorderStreamType.Preview and startRecording with streamType is streamTypeVideo . I have successfully saved the video to the gallery, but it does not include audio.
_mediaRecorder ??= await _engine.createMediaRecorder(
    const RecorderStreamInfo(type: RecorderStreamType.preview));

 await _mediaRecorder
        ?.startRecording(MediaRecorderConfiguration(storagePath: p,
        streamType: MediaRecorderStreamType.streamTypeVideo,
        containerFormat: MediaRecorderContainerFormat.formatMp4,
    ));

After that, I changed streamTypeVideo to streamTypeBoth , but encountered the error Agora Exception with code is -3 and message  null  at startRecoding function in MediaRecoderImpl class
await _mediaRecorder
        ?.startRecording(MediaRecorderConfiguration(storagePath: p,
        streamType: MediaRecorderStreamType.streamTypeBoth,
        containerFormat: MediaRecorderContainerFormat.formatMp4,
    ));

final callApiResult = await irisMethodChannel.invokeMethod(
        IrisMethodCall(apiType, jsonEncode(param), buffers: buffers));
    if (callApiResult.irisReturnCode < 0) {
      throw AgoraRtcException(code: callApiResult.irisReturnCode);
    }

I kindly ask everyone to guide me on how to record both video and audio. Is this feasible, and could you suggest how I might implement it? Thank you all very much!
